# Validation in a Doctrine entity where that property itself is an Entity derived from another entity using constraints

Tags: forms, symfony, validation, doctrine, constraints

First of all I hope this question is allowed because I guess its a rather framework-specific question (Symfony). I am running into the following problem:

A form is submitted and checked for validity for creating a new 'Toernooionderdeel' and as a result the Persist and Flush operations of Doctrine for this Entity are to be called attempting to put the newly created entity into the database. Fairly basic stuff to this point. But the form fails at ->isValid() before persisting and flushing can commence.

In my case the Constraints are applied on properties in various ways through annotation. 
@Assert\Valid specifically is used on properties that define ManyToOne relationships with other entities and it all works fine, until...

I attempt to use @Assert\Valid on a property of 'Toernooionderdeel' called '$toernooi' which represents a ManyToOne relationship (Toernooionderdeel -> Toernooi). 
The difference between this one and the other relationships I validate in the same way is that this 'Toernooi' Entity is derived from another entity, where the other entities aren't.

Despite obviously having a 'Toernooi' defined under the '$toernooi' property of 'Toernooionderdeel', the Constraint detects it as a violation and thus the form doesnt pass validation.

What things do i have to consider when doing this type of validation (using Constraints) on an 'advanced' entity construction like this? Has any of you done this before and if so, how did you do it?

Comment: the first question that comes to mind: does the Toernooi entity already exist beforehand or is it cascade-persisted and does it itself have constraints that have to be fulfilled (then the cascaded persist would fail, since Assert\Valid only demands that it's a valid entity afaik ... and probably has to be persisted already?)

Comment: @Jakumi your question sent me in the right direction. The entity existed beforehand and has constraints by itself. I thereby found out that in the form validator the getViolations function produced an array with violations that were related to the Toernooi entity. Root cause found, time for some basic problem solving on the entity Toernooi :) Thanks my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the entity referenced in a property ("child") is validated in the parent object via Assert\Valid, it's validity is also checked. When the child entity isn't valid, the parent isn't valid either (transitive).

Comment: Specific to this scenario it means that if the child property is an object, all the @Assert's (Constraints) in that object will be validated ('asserted') aswell.